# Dropzone.js - How to add new property to file object after uploading file

Tags: javascript, jquery, file-upload, dropzone.js

I'm using dropzone and PHP to upload and delete files. When I load my upload page I create some mockfiles with the following params: name, size, thumbnail and id. This mock is set using pre uploaded data.

So when someone click on remove file button, I call the php method that delete the image.

My problem is when the user uploads an file and tries to delete it without loading the page. When it happens, dropzone file object just can't be altered.

I'm trying:

```
var dropZone3 = new Dropzone("#file3",{
                    init: function() {
                        this.on('success', function (file) {
                            console.log(file);
                            file['test'] = 'test';
                            file.test = 'test';
                            console.log(file);
                        })
                    },
                    paramName: 'file3',
                    autoProcessQueue:true,
                    uploadMultiple: false,
                    parallelUploads: 1,
                    maxFiles: 3,
                    maxFilesize: 5,
                    addRemoveLinks: true
```

My problem is that the first console.log and the second one inside init on success function shows me the same file.

Anyone knows how to fix it?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 9):

It's possible to add properties directly to `file` object (dropzone v4.3.0)

```
var dropZone = new Dropzone(document.querySelector('.js-dropzone'), {
  url: '/file/upload'
});

dropZone.on('success', function (file, response) {
  var res = JSON.parse(response);

  if (res.result == true) {
    file.test = 'test';
    file.id = res.id;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't think you can add a property to the file object when is already uploaded, but you can add it before on the `accept` property:

```
var dropZone3 = new Dropzone("#file3", {
    url: "upload.php",
    init: function () {
        this.on('success', function (file) {
            console.log(file);
        })
    },
    accept: function(file, done) {
        file.test = "test";
        return done();
    },
    paramName: 'file3',
    autoProcessQueue: true,
    uploadMultiple: false,
    parallelUploads: 1,
    maxFiles: 3,
    maxFilesize: 5,
    addRemoveLinks: true
});
```